# How to pass an instance of a service to a react router component in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

We have the following code:

```
//routes.tsx
const auth = new AuthService();

export default <Route component={ Layout }>
    <Route path='/login' components={{body:Login}}
</Route>;

//layout.tsx
export interface LayoutProps {
    body: React.ReactElement<any>
}
```

I'd like for the Login component to have access to the authentication service that is instantiated in the routes.tsx

The way I understand it, I have to add something to the LayoutProps interface but I can't find the type that would allow the instance of the AuthService to be passed.

Comment: maybe this is not the best practice but you can export the AuthService from the routes file `export const auth = new AuthService()`, then you can import it in layout.tsx `import { auth } from './routes'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was:

export const auth = new AuthService()

in the AuthService file. At the same time I would not export the type.

That way any class that needed the auth service would only have to import the instance from the file and they could not create another instance.